# How to create custom shipping method for the Cash On deliver Eligible Payment method

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.3, magento2.3.4, custom-shipping-method

I want to create custom shipping method with custom price shipping method and it will be show if the customer will eligible to the cash on delivery, if the customer will not eligible for cash on delivery then that custom shipping method should be not display in frontend , how can i achieve that in magento2?

Comment: How order will eligible for COD ? As we know payment method will select after shipping selection.

Comment: We can set the backend where if COD is applicable if the order is above something price , if the COD is available then that custom shipping method should display